# SQl Insert code issue

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write two SQL queries to write back data. One is an INSERT and one is an UPDATE. I need to round a dollar amount to two decimal positions. Can you help with the syntax on both queries - I don't know how the CAST differs between INSERT and UPDATE. Here is what I have so far:

The INSERT:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ORDERSHIPPINGBOX WHERE OrderSplitID={0:OrderNumber} AND TRACKINGNUMBER={0:Pin})
INSERT INTO OrderShippingBox (OrderSplitID, ABoxNumber, TrackingNumber, BoxWeight, BoxL, BoxW, BoxH,ShippingCharge)
Values ({0:OrderNumber},{0:PackageNumber}, {0:Pin}, {0:Weight}, {0:DimL},{0:DimW},{0:DimH},{0:EstimatedRate})
```

The UPDATE:

```
UPDATE OrderShippingBox 
SET ShippingCharge=CAST({0:EstimatedRate} as DECIMAL(12,2),
WHERE OrderSplitID={0:OrderNumber}
```

In both cases the EstimatedRate needs to round to 2 decimal positions. I think I have the UPDATE correct, but can you confirm? I need help with the INSERT.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Also, you're missing a closing parenthesis in your CAST in the update.

Comment: If you want only two decimal places for `ShippingCharge` then declare it as `decimal(12,2)` in the `OrderShippingBox` table.